# The difference between barycentric and parallel coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, barycentric-coordinates

I am studying for an exam tomorrow and there are some topics which I do not understand from the slides of the professor.

If anyone could give me a clear explanation, I would be eternally grateful.

1. What are barycentric coordinates?
2. What are parallel coordinates?
3. What are the differences between barycentric and parallel
   coordinates?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to Google that up (to begin with)?

Comment: Of course. The problem is I couldn't understand the answers that Google brought me.

Comment: These systems both represent data in an alternative way. That's all. Beside that, they have nothing in common. Barycentric coordinates have a mathematical background. Parallel coordiantes are **only** a means of representation with no mathematics behind them. A rather elementary presentation of barycentric coordinates can be found in (http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/GeometryTriangleBarycentricCoordinates.aspx). A very interesting but more difficult paper for you is (http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Barycentric_A07.pdf)